Determining if the function converges uniformly
Consider the sequnce $f_n$ of function where $f_n:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by the following
$f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}, \forall ,x \in \mathbb{R}$
Find the point-wise limit of the function of this sequence as $n \to \infty$ and hence determine whether or not the sequence converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$
Below shows my approach, however have some confusion surrounding the question:
$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}$
Dividing throughout by n we get the following:
$f_n(x) \to \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} = 1$
I was considering looking at different intervals for the function for example $x = 0, x> 0$ and $ x< 0$, but then this would create a piece wise limit function which changes the fact that I am thinking the general limit $\to 1$.
The second part of the question states determine if it's uniformly convergent:
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = |\frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} - 1|$$
$$= \frac{nx - \sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} < \frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}$$
Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} = 1$$
Given
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \to 1$$
Hence it doesn't conform uniformly.

If you took the supremum with respect to $x$, then how did you end up with having a variable $x$ in expression?

The limiting function is not $f=1$. As you pointed out, it is $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\mathrm{sign}(x)$ otherwise. What can you say now about uniform convergence?

@Andrew just to confirm the limit then maps to a piece-wise function cause I would of generated that initially when I was doing it but was wondering if that was correct. I would of evlaued the limit at x = 0, x < 0 and x > 0 which would of generated a piece wise function and I'm guessing the sup would have to be evaluated individually for each ?

Sequence consist from continuous functions, but limit is discontinuous.

When we find the piecewise limit we get for $x\neq 0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{nx} {\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} = \frac{x}{|x|} =  \text{sgn} (x) $$
while for $x=0$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(0) = 0$$
hence
$$\text{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases}
-1 & \text{if} \ x<0\\
0 & \text{if} \ x=0\\
1 & \text{if} \ x>0\\
\end{cases}$$
and our limit function is discontinuous but it's true that

Let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of continuous function from $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ if $f_n \to f$ uniformly then $f$ is continuous

Since we're starting with continuous functions and end up with a discontinuos function we conclude uniform convergence isn't achievable.

I hope this helps!

Note If we were to restrict domain to $(0,+\infty)$ (or $(-\infty, 0 )$ is basically the same) we have
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align*}
\bigg | \frac{nx} {\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} - 1 \bigg| & = \bigg | \frac{nx-\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}} {\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}  \bigg|\\
& =\bigg| \frac{\cancel {nx}\bigg[1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2x^2}}\bigg]} {\cancel {nx}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2x^2}}}\bigg|\\
&=_{n\to \infty }  \frac{1}{n^2x^2}
\end{align*}$$
this means that fixing $x_0 \in \Bbb R$
$$\frac{1}{n^2x_0^2} < \varepsilon \iff n > \frac{1}{\sqrt{\varepsilon}x_0}$$
so neither on a restricted domain we could get along with U.C.

$\frac{x}{|x|} =  \text{sgn} (x)$ is not correct, as left side have no sense for $x=0$.

@zkutch of course! I was trying to condensate a little bit, on my way to edit for clarification.


How is $\bigg|\frac{nx}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}-1\bigg| = \frac{nx-\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}{\sqrt{1+n^2x^2}}$? What if $x$ is negative?

So, it is quite difficult to accept what you did. Firstly, notice that if
$$f(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x),$$
then
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
                     1 \quad &\text{if $x > 0$}\\
                     -1 \quad &\text{if $x<0$} \\
                     0 \quad &\text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
The second part on uniform convergence is, as said in comments, easy to observe. If the sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly, the the limit function is also continuous. Since the limit function is not continuous, the sequence is not uniformly convergent.
However, for the second part on uniform convergence, I also suggest an alternate way which requires only the criteria that you are using to test uniform convergence. I leave it to you to prove this easy fact:

Fact Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ on $D\subset \mathbb{R}$ pointwise and that there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $D$  such that
$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| \not\to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$, then $\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly to $f$ on $D$.

If you choose $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then $f(x_n) = 1$ and $f_n(x_n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Thus
$$|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| = 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \not\to 0,$$ as $n\to \infty$. Thus,
$\{f_n\}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.
